# Unpack vector to variables in C

Tags: c, vector, opencl

In Python, I can initialize variables with itterables and automatic unpacking like in

```
a,b,c = [1,2,5]
```

In (openCL) C, can I do something similar, like so

```
uint4 vec = (uint4)(1,2,3,4);
uint a,b,c,d;
a,b,c,d = vec;
```

or do I have to use explicit vector components? Or is there any other good way to do this in a simple and correct way?

Comment: Please, what is `uint4`?

Comment: How about `uint v[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};`?

Comment: It is an OpenCL unsigned integer 4-vector.

Comment: @alk 4-vector, not vector and in OpenCL not in C. That's two differences. Imagine a `struct` containing 4 `uint`s name x,y,z,w. Such data structures allow vectored memory access which is pretty important when it comes to HPC library like OpenCL.

Comment: @pSoLT: Just noticed that his isn't (directly) C related. Sry, I deleted my comment you now referred to ("*'vector*' in C? Hmm ...").

Comment: @alk: This seems to be basicC. OpenCL is just a library.

Comment: Why do you expect two very different languages to have the same features? What did you find out yourself?

Comment: I know, how to do `uint a = vec.s0` etc. I just am looking for a way, not having to write this expression once for every component. (And no, for loop doesn't solve the answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign values to each of the variables separately. You of course can write some specific function/macro do this task, but it's not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

In C, the syntax for this is something like this:

```
yourType variablename[] = {yourdata};
```

You can even nest vectors if you are working with more than one variable

```
yourType variablename[][] = {{yourdata1},{yourdata2},...};
```

And you can use this even if you are trying to initialize a struct, but you must input the arguments in the same order as you declared on your struct

```
struct yourStruct {
type1 name1;
type2 name2;
type3 name3;
...
}

struct yourStruct variablename = {(type1) data1, (type2) data2, (type3) data3...};
```

And you can also nest a struct inside a struct, or a struct inside a vector, or a vector inside a struct, and so on and so forth...

Just be careful with pointers. They are not explicitly different from vectors, but should you try to initialize a pointer like a vector you will get a lot of nasty errors, and likely loose a few days trying to fix them.

Comment: I am not sure, if this answers my question. As I understand it, I want to do exactly the opposite way of what you are showing.

Comment: Well... i think you will have to delve with variadic functions/macros to do something like that...